# How can i upload image from front-end in magento?

Tags: magento, module

I am trying to upload single image from front-end in my custom module. This is my form in test/template/test.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('text/index/save') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="sb_link">Image</label>
<input type="file" id="bs_image" name="bs_image" required="true"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Here is my controller where i am uploading images in media folder and saving name in databse.

```
<?php

public function saveAction() {
    echo $path = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/test';
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 777, true);
    }
    try {
        $fname = $_FILES['test']['name'];
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('test');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'docx'));
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $uploader->save($path, $fname);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    $contact = Mage::getModel('test/test');
    $contact->setData('bs_image', $bs_image);
    $contact->save();

    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```

I am getting this error.Error Message: File was not uploaded. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked your code. In form you use the name as **bs_image** for image field. But in controller you get the post file as **$_FILES['test']['name'];**. Change this to **$_FILES['bs_image']['name'];** .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have put end form tag  in your file.
You need to access file name like this 
 $fname = $_FILES['bs_image']['name'];